# Which episodes are required to watch before jumping directly into Star Trek: Voyager?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, suggested-order

I want to introduce Star Trek to a girl (who doesn't know anything about Star Trek) and I am thinking about *Star Trek: Voyager* because it features a female captain.

What episodes should I present to her before that? Probably, the episode from *Star Trek: The Next Generation* in which USS Voyager lost from alpha quadrant (episode name not in my mind). Any more episode?

I am too much into the feeling of Star Trek, so I am unable to emulate condition of a Star Trek virgin. Please, help.

Species intro isn't that necessary (except Borg of course), but I'd like your help in this matter. And, if some episodes can be skipped using small mouth-telling story from small portion of that episode, tell me that too.

Comment: None. Just drop her straight into it.

Comment: Q-who maybe, to introduce Q and the Borg. Maybe The Maquis 1 and 2, to explain where Chakotey and his crew come from. But those aren't strictly necessary and may confuse her with unnecessary details (people, places etc). You could probably do like Richard said and just drop her into it.

Comment: I think this question is too opinion based. However, my opinion is that the series is designed to introduce new viewers. There's always going to be odds and ends from others but starting from the beginning of the series is pretty much the best chance you're going to have!

Comment: @Liath This is similar to viewing order questions. So, I don't think it's opinion based.

Comment: @Liath This isn't that different from [Will I be able to follow the story if I skip The Next Generation & watch Deep Space 9 directly?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9036/will-i-be-able-to-follow-the-story-if-i-skip-the-next-generation-watch-deep-sp)

Comment: I don't know what TNG episode you're referring to that had Voyager in it...

Comment: He means the first episode of voyager, which was a ds9 crossover

Comment: @Izkata No, this isn't a duplicate as audience here hasn't seen *Star Trek: The Next Generation* (In fact, none of Star Trek things)...

Comment: @SachinShekhar The answers do explain where the crossover points are, though, so it does answer this question - nothing is required, but you might get some extra background with a Maquis episode or two, as well as the movie _First Contact_ for later Voyager episodes

Comment: It's true you really don't need any primers to watch Voyager but as someone who has watched it, you should do better to re-watch [TNG](http://www.hulu.com/star-trek-the-next-generation) or [DS9](http://www.hulu.com/star-trek-deep-space-nine)!! [Voyager](http://www.tv.com/shows/star-trek-voyager/forums/suggested-streamlined-viewing-of-voyager-or-the-way-not-to-hate-this-show-378-3380446) is uneven, has only two likable characters and doesn't even make sense within it's own established reality... sadly =[

Comment: DS9 is a superior show in every capacity. Don't put her through Voyager just because there's a female captain.

Comment: "if some episodes can be skipped using small mouth-telling": To be quite honest, you may skip VOY entirely. Yet if do want to continue, definitely avoid "Threshold". Even its author does not consider that episode to be canon anymore.

Comment: And I really do recommend  watching DS9 over VOY. Its first two seasons are rough, yet after the setup it features the best Star Trek show. The story arcs matter whereas VOY is quite like TNG with its alien of the week approach, yet worse as it uses the reset button on almost each episode, solves issues through technobabble, and characters don't really evolve. (Poor Harry Kim.) They basically have all the abilities the plot requires them to have, e.g. (Tom Paris is a pilot, ship engineer, doctor, holo-suite programmer). IMO VOY is a  study on wasted potential.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since *Star Trek: Voyager* operates mainly in the Delta quadrant, far from the rest of the Federation, the series doesn't depend much on backstory or characters from the earlier series.  You should show her the *Next Generation* episodes that introduce crossover characters and societies that play a significant role in *Voyager*.

1. Reginald Barclay, introduced in TNG's "Hollow Pursuits", recurs in "Pathfinder".
2. The Barzan Wormhole, introduced in TNG's "The Price", revisited in "False Profits".
3. The Borg, introduced in TNG's "Q Who", recurs in "Scorpion" and the character Seven of Nine in seasons 4-7.
4. Q, introduced in TNG's "Encounter at Farpoint", recurs in "Death Wish", "The Q and the Grey", and "Q2".

Comment: Good list of crossovers. But I can't help thinking odd TNG episodes throw in out of order/context will be more jarring than the value they'll add to watching voyager.

Comment: @Liath Perhaps.  Unlike DS9, TNG was quite episodic and you could watch the shows in most any order and it wouldn't matter, the two part episodes being the primary exceptions to the rule.

Answer (score 10):

No prerequisites are required.

Voyager is a standalone show with standalone plots and characters. As you watch the first few episodes, you will be introduced to the characters.

True, there are a few villains that appear from TNG (Q and the Borg). But think about it: if you show your friend a random Borg or Q episode from TNG, you'll be throwing a bunch of other characters at her that she's never been introduced to. (If you show her the TNG pilot, she'll be introduced to both Q and the TNG crew, but then she will probably be disappointed when you won't let her continue to watch that series.)

Just fill her in with a couple of sentences about who Q and the Borg are, and answer any questions she has. She'll be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

All Star Trek shows TOS, Next Gen, DS9, VOY, Enterprise are pretty much on their own, as they have no relation to each other except they all take place on Starfleet vessels.

As an example:

**TOS** Has general missions and adventures in each episode.

**TNG**, Same as TOS, general missions and adventures in each episode.

**DS9**, Is about the Maquis, Cardassians and The Dominion, pretty much centered on a space station.

**VOY** is about a ship getting lost in the Delta Quadrant of the galaxy trying to get back home. It's similar to TNG only we see the Borg a lot after season 3.

**Enterprise** is when it all began, the adventures in space and personally this was my favourite show but it only lasted for 4 seasons.

Comment: DS9 introduced the Maquis as a setup for VOY. (Though on VOY the Maquis had basically no effect. They behaved just as starfleet personal almost right from the start.)